# How to add completion handler/closure for 'animated: true'

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationbar, completionhandler

Is there a way to give an animation completion closure for a `UINavigationController` animation?

I have a line such as,

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
```

and I want to detect when it's completed.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { print("Finished") }
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(!navigationController!.navigationBarHidden, animated: true)
CATransaction.commit()
```

You can wrap it around with `CATransaction`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, I think navigationBarHidden booleans are not behaving as expected. What is the trick behind it? What should I observe. It feels like it's behaving on its own even when I use true or false